# Using Pandas: function matches column name, unable to perform function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting, attributeerror

I was given a table by a client named with a column named "**rank**", 
and I'm trying to convert the values in that column to an int type, but when I try to run the df.rank.astype(int) function on the column it thinks I'm trying to run the .astype() function on the .rank() function. Any way to prevent this?

```
df.rank.astype()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Comment: `df['rank'].astype(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set declare the column using []

```
df['rank'] = df['rank'].astpye()
```